# SSDT: Create publish profile for disconnected database

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

Here's my scenario:

- I have an SSDT project in VS2012 to design a database
- I have another SSDT project for a reference database
- I have a bunch of synonyms in the first development database, pointing to the reference database using a SQLCMD variable
- I have two "publish" profiles for servers in my environment, each get a different value for the SQLCMD

Now, I need a third publish profile for a production database, to which I have no connection. I just need to generate a script with a specific value for my SQLCMD variable. When I create a new profile, it is mandatory that I provide a target server before I can hit the "Generate script" button.

How can I create a profile in which I specify a SQLCMD and just generate the script, **without having a connection to the target server**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look into getting a build box with rights to that server to run the jobs to generate the scripts. You won't be able to generate the proper script unless someone can guarantee that the target schema matches that against which you're generating the scripts. We use Jenkins and the service account for that has rights to do the necessary DB calls to generate a script (and push the changes in our case).

Comment: Excellent comment, but in my case, the database only contains views and SPs pointing to another DB. I am mandated to produce scripts that will drop & recreate all views and SPs. Since everything is recreated, I don't necessary need a delta of the two DBs...

Comment: That's going to be hard to do w/ SSDT. It's designed to push changes by doing a diff. Same w/ Red-Gate's SQL Source Control. Only way I can think to gen up the "Create" part would be to point to an empty database, but that wouldn't give you a DROP as well. You'd have to write that up yourself. Using a build server w/ permissions would get around this, but it wouldn't easily give you a drop/create for all objects, just an ALTER if there's a diff.